# Searching for string withing string in JS issue

Tags: javascript

i am using HTML5 and indexOf gives me an error, so what else can i use to search for the word "correct" in a string: `a001_new_quiz_multiple_choice_new_mc4_correct.html` which is in a variable called `value1`

```
function SetAPIValue(key1, value1)
{
   // alert("action is " + key1 + " and data is " + value1);
   console.log(value1);

   var str = "wrong";
   var n = str.search(value1);
   if (n > 0)
     alert("found");
}
```

the error i get: 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

Comment: "indexOf gives me an error" ? What error ?

Comment: please see OP  for error :) thanks

Comment: oops yes i guess i will get error if value1 is null :) my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you used indexOf, but this works :

```
var value1 = "a001_new_quiz_multiple_choice_new_mc4_correct.html";
var n = value1.indexOf("correct");
if (n >= 0) alert("found");
```

Maybe you tried `"correct".indexOf(value1);` instead of `value1.indexOf("correct");` ?

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gUdjD/)

Answer (score 0):

Does this error happens on IE only?
If so - you should note that indexOf is not implemented in their JS enjoy. 
Try adding the following code before the first usage in indexOf:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're confused : OP was calling indexOf on a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

> function SetAPIValue(key1, value1)
>   {
>        var regEx = new RegExp("correct");
>        alert(regEx.test(value1));
>   }